# Report Expression to SUM [Column A] values for records with null/empty values in [Column B]

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, expression, rdl

I am working on an existing SSRS report and have the following situation:

1. It is working well and displays grouped data from a stored procedure
2. A request has been made to SUM values of certain column(say Quantity) ONLY when values are empty/null in a certain field (Defeted - Bit field with a NULL Default)
3. E.g

Products Table

```
+----+--------------+----------+----------+
| ID | PRODUCTNAME  | QUANTITY | DEFECTED |
+----+--------------+----------+----------+
|    |              |          |          |
| 1  | Ice Cream    | 8        | 1        |
|    |              |          |          |
| 2  | Soap         | 3        |          |
|    |              |          |          |
| 3  | Kit Kat      | 10       |          |
|    |              |          |          |
| 4  | Baked Beans  | 2        | 0        |
|    |              |          |          |
| 5  | Toilet Paper | 2        |          |
+----+--------------+----------+----------+
```

I would like to have an expression that calculates the **Total quantity of PRODUCTS whose DEFECTED status is NULL/Empty (not 1 or 0)**

i.e It should be total for the following:

**Soap + Kit Kat + Toilet Paper = 3 + 10 + 2 = 15**

My attempt is:

```
Sum(IFF(First(Fields!Defected.Value, "Products_Report_Data_Set_Name") = "",First(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Products_Report_Data_Set_Name"),0))
```

Where `Products_Report_Data_Set_Name` returns the list of Products

Its not working

Can I solve it through an expression? Or will I have to add another data set?

Comment: If possible get another column saying isDefected True/False value and do group by on that column to get Sum of Defected & not defected both

Comment: Hi @Naveen. Thanks for the reply, but you're not answering my question. Even if it was what I was looking for, that scenario is covered with the DEFECTED column which is a bit field. So adding another True/False column wouldve been redundant

Comment: @NaveenKumar I realise the naming could have misled you, so just edited and added that DEFECTED is a bit field.

Comment: OK, then i think try with ISNothing(Fields!Defected.Value) in your expression

Comment: @NaveenKumar At what point though? Do you mind typing out the entire expression? Is it Sum(IFF(IsNothing(Fields!Defected.Value, "Products_Report_Data_Set_Name"),First(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Products_Report_Data_Set_Name"),0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
= IIF(Fields!Defected.Value = "", SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value), Nothing)
```

Hope this should work as expected.